# Show that conditional expectation is $ P[ E < 7-T-B \mid T,B] = \max(0, 1-e^{-(7-T-B)})$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am reading the book [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](https://books.google.de/books?id=Y5bxBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I try to understand his calculation in **Section 2.3 Another Simple Example**.

In this section, he has three random Variables $T,B,E$ wihch are i.i.d exponential random variables( i.e. they have density $e^{-u}$ on $[0,\infty)$. He claims that a simple calculation shows that

$$ P[ E < 7-T-B \mid T,B] = \max(0, 1-e^{-(7-T-B)})$$

Can someone explain me what exactly happened here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you read that book? if you are doing PhD in maths?

Comment: About your question: you really do not need any proof for that. $T$ and $B$ are given because of $..|T,B$. If something is given, then they are automatically deterministic and if some deterministic thing is scalar, then it IS constant. If you relly want to show that it is the case, then treat them as random variables which are degenerate at limits ($n\rightarrow \infty$) and obtain the probability over the joint PDF in terms of $n$. Then, check your result for $n\rightarrow\infty$. You will get exactly the same result given in the answer, no matter which distribution you choose for $T$ and $B$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I read that book for fun, I already finished my PhD.  I have a measure theoretic background and its not immediately clear to me how the transformation from conditional expectation to the probability happens. I am pretty sure there exists a solid argumentation for it.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören but what would be wrong with reading such a book during your phd?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Normally pattern recognation applications are mostly irrelevant for pure math PhD work. In some cases, one gets PhD money from engineering departments and they also have to do some applications. Another possibility could be just to learn applications out of curiosity. I was only wondering which one was that. I know the first two authors of this book. I am still surprised that they wrote an application oriented book. I have to admit that there is a very big difference from the books written by engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are interested in follows from the more general fact below, considering $X=E$, $Y=(T,B)$, and $h(t,b)=7-t-b$. One sees that the distribution of $(T,B)$ is irrelevant, as long as $(T,B)$ is independent of $E$ and $E$ is exponentially distributed.

> Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and that $X$ has CDF $F_X$, then, for every measurable function $h$, $$P(X<h(Y)\mid Y)=F_X(h(Y))$$

To prove this, recall that, by definition, $P(X<h(Y)\mid Y)=g(Y)$ where the measurable function $g$ is characterized by the fact that, for every $y$, $$P(X<h(Y),Y<y)=E(g(Y);Y<y)$$ Now, by definition of the distribution $P_Y$ of $Y$, the RHS is $$\int_{-\infty}^yg(z)dP_Y(z)$$ and, by independence, the LHS is $$\int_{-\infty}^y\left(\int_{-\infty}^{h(z)}dP_X(x)\right)dP_Y(z)=\int_{-\infty}^yF_X(h(z))dP_Y(z)$$ By identification, this proves that $g=F_X\circ h$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering all the time where the independence comes into play. So you used that for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Z: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $\int f(Z) dP = \int f(x,y) dP_Z(x,y)$, and then using $Z:=(X,Y)$ we get from independence $P_Z = P_X \cdot P_Y$ and then you used Fubini? Really nice, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$\mathsf P(T+B+E<7|T,B)$ is the probability that $T+B+E<7$ given the values of $T$ and $B$. Thus $T$ and $B$ are constants. Now you can solve the equation for $E$.

$T+B+E<7 \Rightarrow E<7-T-B$

And $E$ is exponentially distributed.

$\mathsf P(E<x)=1-e^{-x}, x>0$

For $x=7-T-B$ we get

$$\mathsf P(E<7-T-B|T,B)=1-e^{-(7-T-B)}=1-e^{T+B-7} \quad \text{on the event}\ \{7-B-T >0\}$$

Comment: `Thus T and B are constants` I understand the interpretation, but I am still surprised from that transformation from the conditioned expectation to the normal probability. Is there a theorem or something similar which states that? I can't find anything like this in my probability book.

Comment: @Adam What you might find in your book are statements such as, if $(X,Y)$ is independent, then $$P(X<Y\mid Y)=F(Y)$$ where $F$ denotes the CDF of $X$. This is what is used here.

Comment: @Did do you have a reference for this statement? I could not find it nor proof it for myself.

Comment: @Adam Such direct consequences of the definitions, depending on the book, can be suggested as an exercise or squarely omitted. I posted a full proof.